# Multiple file uploads issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

I have a simple code to upload multiple images that uploads the image to a folder and saves the path to the database. The problem is I have 3 browse buttons. The script only uploads the files and saves the path to the database when all the three browse buttons are selected with images. But when I select only 1 image to upload the script does not works. What is the matter?

Here is my current script.

```
<?php
include'includes/db.php';
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $extension = substr($_FILES['photo1']['name'],
    strrpos($_FILES['photo1']['name'], '.'));

    $extension = substr($_FILES['photo2']['name'],
    strrpos($_FILES['photo2']['name'], '.'));

    $extension = substr($_FILES['photo3']['name'],
    strrpos($_FILES['photo3']['name'], '.'));


     $extension = strtolower($extension);
     echo $extension;

    if( $extension == ".jpg" || $extension == ".jpeg" || $extension ==  ".gif" || $extension == ".png" )
    {
        $img1=$_FILES['photo1']['name'];
        $img2=$_FILES['photo2']['name'];
        $img3=$_FILES['photo3']['name'];

        $size=$_FILES['photo']['size'];
        $type=$_FILES['photo']['type'];

        $temp1=$_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'];
        $temp2=$_FILES['photo2']['tmp_name'];
        $temp3=$_FILES['photo3']['tmp_name'];

        $limit_size = 1024000; 
        $size_in_kb = 1024; 
        $max_size = $limit_size/$size_in_kb; 


        if($size > $limit_size)
        {
            echo "<script>location.replace('test.php?err=File size exceeds $max_size KB')</script>";    

        }
        else 
        {
            move_uploaded_file($temp1,"images/".$img1);
            move_uploaded_file($temp2,"images/".$img2);
            move_uploaded_file($temp3,"images/".$img3);

            $sql2="INSERT INTO ad_images(image1, image2, image3)VALUES('$img1', '$img2', '$img3')";
            $res2=mysql_query($sql2);

            if($res2){
            echo "<script>location.replace('test.php?success=Product added successfuly')</script>";
            }else{
            echo "<script>location.replace('test.php?vlx=Error. Try Again...')</script>";
        }
     }
   }
 }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Script Testing</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p> Upload Image<br />
        <input type="file" name="photo1" id="photo"><br />
        <input type="file" name="photo2" id="photo"><br />
        <input type="file" name="photo3" id="photo"><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Add Product" style="margin-top: 25px; margin-left: 335px;"/>
  </p>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't get whats wrong in my code everything seems to be fine. Please help.

************ SOLVED ***************

I was using the same variable extension. Now solved.

Here is my new code.

```
<?php
include'includes/db.php';
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $extension1 = substr($_FILES['photo1']['name'],
    strrpos($_FILES['photo1']['name'], '.'));

    $extension2 = substr($_FILES['photo2']['name'],
    strrpos($_FILES['photo2']['name'], '.'));

    $extension3 = substr($_FILES['photo3']['name'],
    strrpos($_FILES['photo3']['name'], '.'));


     $extension1 = strtolower($extension1);
     echo $extension1;

     $extension2 = strtolower($extension2);
     echo $extension2;

     $extension3 = strtolower($extension3);
     echo $extension3;

    if( $extension1 == ".jpg" || $extension1 == ".jpeg" || $extension1 ==   ".gif" || $extension1 == ".png" ||
        $extension2 == ".jpg" || $extension2 == ".jpeg" || $extension2 ==   ".gif" || $extension2 == ".png" ||
        $extension3 == ".jpg" || $extension3 == ".jpeg" || $extension3 ==   ".gif" || $extension3 == ".png" )
    {
        $img1=$_FILES['photo1']['name'];
        $img2=$_FILES['photo2']['name'];
        $img3=$_FILES['photo3']['name'];

        $size=$_FILES['photo']['size'];
        $type=$_FILES['photo']['type'];

        $temp1=$_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'];
        $temp2=$_FILES['photo2']['tmp_name'];
        $temp3=$_FILES['photo3']['tmp_name'];

        $limit_size = 1024000; 
        $size_in_kb = 1024; 
        $max_size = $limit_size/$size_in_kb; 


        if($size > $limit_size)
        {
            echo "<script>location.replace('test.php?err=File size exceeds $max_size KB')</script>";    

        }
        else 
        {
            move_uploaded_file($temp1,"images/".$img1);
            move_uploaded_file($temp2,"images/".$img2);
            move_uploaded_file($temp3,"images/".$img3);

            $sql2="INSERT INTO ad_images(image1, image2, image3)VALUES('$img1', '$img2', '$img3')";
            $res2=mysql_query($sql2);

            if($res2){
            echo "<script>location.replace('test.php?success=Product added successfuly')</script>";
            }else{
            echo "<script>location.replace('test.php?vlx=Error. Try Again...')</script>";
        }
     }
   }
 }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Script Testing</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p> Upload Image<br />
        <input type="file" name="photo1" id="photo"><br />
        <input type="file" name="photo2" id="photo"><br />
        <input type="file" name="photo3" id="photo"><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Add Product" style="margin-top: 25px; margin-left: 335px;"/>
  </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dont have any knowledge of the PHP. But you should check your uplaod box before moving the files and updating the database if they contain the data and if contain then do the operations  accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your concern but if you don't have any knowledge of PHP then probably this question is not for you. Thanks again.

Comment: IT's not syntax I am telling you . But it's logic if you process the empty upload boxes then it bound to throw error like this line `$extension = substr($_FILES['photo1']['name'],
    strrpos($_FILES['photo1']['name'], '.'));` if the upload box is empty then `substring`  function will throw the exception. Then again what should I know.:)

Comment: *"select only 1 image to upload the script does not works"*  you are trying to upload only single file with this code `move_uploaded_file($temp1,"images/".$img1);
            move_uploaded_file($temp2,"images/".$img2);
            move_uploaded_file($temp3,"images/".$img3);` i think it will effect to your code.

Comment: So thats the hidden talent man... you know PHP.. ;)

Comment: @ketan man I am saying that I have problem in uploading a single file but when I select all the three files the images are uploaded and paths are saved to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because u take the same variable $extension and if the third browse field will not be choosen , after submit it will be blank and it will not entered into the upload if condition. If u will browse only from third browse button then that single file will be uploaded.

Comment: let me try it with extension1 , extension2 and extension3

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple attribute to upload multiple files throw a single browse button eg

```
<input type="file" name="img" multiple>
```

You can use ctrl to select  multiple images

Comment: I want to user 3 different browse buttons. I do not want to use 1 browse buttons to upload multiple images